# ALTER VIEW to add select statement to UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now I have a view that looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW fruits AS
SELECT A, B, C
  FROM apple
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, C
  FROM banana
```

When I add the `cherry` table to my project I would like to do something like this:

```
ALTER VIEW fruits ADD
SELECT A, B, C
  FROM cherry
```

Obviously that does not work.

What kind of creative solutions can SO come up with to help me manage this view?

The context of this is that this database supports an application that uses plug in architecture so as plugins are activated the view needs to change.

[EDIT] Please do not get distracted with the simplicity of the tables.  The real tables are more complex and not subject to being merged.   The new tables are part of the installed plugin and would not be in the initial install of the system.  If we can't find a database way to change the view then we will make this a DBA procedure to follow when a new plugin is installed.

Comment: It's not "creative", but have you considering fixing your design? Clearly the table name is being as data that should be in a column. You should have one table, and a column for the fruit's name.

Comment: The `alter view` statement must contain the ENTIRE view definition. Write it out with the apple-union-banana-union-cherry and you'll be OK.

Comment: You could change the VIEW to an SP that looks at INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and dynamically builds the UNION statement based on a name or some other application logic (can it know that a new table exists?) in the DB.  The SP could build-up an SQL statement and fire it with the EXEC statement.

Comment: If add a column in view then add statement with alter view will use but if you add few logic or adding new table then change the full defination like alter view name AS select.....

Comment: @RahulBiswas , you can't `ADD` a column to a `VIEW`, you have to `ALTER` the `VIEW` and provide the new definition, which includes the new column in it.

Comment: I wonder what your database would look like once you're reporting on your local supermarket's entire produce department?

Comment: As Stu suggests,  it does appear that there are some relational issues with the DB, but perhaps this is beyond your control? Adding a "type" column to the table, where you could put a value like 'cherry' or 'banana', would go a long way.